# UISplitViewController primary width too narrow

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm trying to present a UISplitViewController as modal on iPad, but I don't seem to have any control over the primary column width. [image]

I've tried setting the `preferredPrimaryColumnWidth`, `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction`, `preferredSplitBehavior` to `.tile`, and the `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth`, but nothing seems to impact it.

If use a `.tripleColumn` Split View I have control, but in `doubleColumn`, it seems I can't control it.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Do you want to get this all setup via code or via storyboard?

Comment: I'm doing it programatically

Answer (score 0):

I was able to setup a UISplitViewController as follows:

```
let sv = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
sv.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
sv.preferredSplitBehavior = .tile
sv.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 1024
sv.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 300
sv.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5
// or sv.preferredPrimaryColumnWidth = 500
```

Of course you need to add view controllers to the primary and detail panes. But this does put the divider in the middle of the screen.

If you are in a `UISplitViewController` subclass that is being created via a storyboard, all of these properties can be setup in the storyboard.

If you are in a `UISplitViewController` subclass you can set the properties in `viewDidLoad` (this also works if the controller is based on a storyboard):

```
self.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
self.preferredSplitBehavior = .tile
self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 1024
self.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 300
self.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5
// or self.preferredPrimaryColumnWidth = 500
```

The `.doubleColumn` style will have been set in the initializer.